# javascript string contains \u0027 after concat strings with '

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services

I am trying to create a string, containing ('). When I send an AJAX post to consume a web service, the string sent, contains \u0027 .Any help?

```
var SearchCriteria = "1=1"; 
        if (tblSYS_SubscribersSearch.value.length > 0) {
            SearchCriteria = "FirstName LIKE N'%" + Criteria + "%' OR LastName LIKE N'%" + Criteria + "%'";
        }
        var settings = {
            "url": "<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndPoint"].ToString()%>" + "/api/SYS_Subscriber/GetListPaged",
            "method": "POST",
            "timeout": 0,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "data": JSON.stringify({
                "ApiKey": Apikey,
                "Fields": Fields,
                "Criteria": SearchCriteria,
                "SortOrder": SortOrder,
                "SortDirection": SortDirection,
                "PageIndex": PageIndex,
                "PageSize": PageSize
            }),
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

`\u0027` is the unicode character for apostrophe (')

You need to add the charset utf-8 for the encoding

Example:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

In HTML file we add

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Ref:- https://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: Thank you for your time, but this didnt help. I think the problem is at SearchCriteria = "FirstName LIKE N'%" + Criteria + "%' OR LastName LIKE N'%" + Criteria + "%'";

Comment: Can you try this FirstName LIKE N\'%\" + Criteria + \"%\' OR LastName LIKE N\'%\" + Criteria + \"%\'